# Hook up to event fired up before RememberMe

Tags: php, symfony, remember-me

I am migrating from old system to new one written in Symfony 2.8.
I want to keep old "RememberMe" cookies but those cookies are not compatible with symfony RememberMe cookie. I thought that I could migrate old cookie to new one, but I don't know whre I can hook up with my migrating class.

Unfortunately method `autoLogin` in `AbstractRememberMeServices` abstract class is declared as `final`. So I need to find another piece of code to override or extend.

Comment: How does your RememberMe cookie look like? It should not be necessary to override `autoLogin`.

Comment: @TobiasXy my RememberMe cookie are actually two cookies. One with username and second with encrypted (two ways) password.